# (Font identification) Univers-like sans-serif

Tags: font-identification

A few days ago, I went to the [Round Tower](http://www.rundetaarn.dk/en/) and happened to see an exhibition called [Natural State of Mind](http://naturalstateofmind.dk/). The exhibition itself was rather uninspiring, but the font they used for signs and things was highly intriguing and very pleasant to the eye.

I took a couple of pictures of it, hoping to identify it on WhatTheFont or IdentiFont—but no dice. IdentiFont could do no better than a few versions of Akzidenz, and WhatTheFont suggested four different versions of Univers and one of Zurich. Both of those are *fairly* close, but clearly not right at all.

Does anyone here know what this font is called?

### Defining features

- The 90° angle at the end of the legs of lowercase x and uppercase A and R
- The only subtly rounded corners
- The tapering shape of the spurs on lowercase ɡ, a, b, d, p, q, etc.
- The relatively close gap between the end of the ‘sticking-out curve’ and the ‘body’ of lowercase a and ɡ
- The square shape of the dot over the i and the comma

### Uppercase (bold)

[image: Uppercase]

### Lowercase (book [?])

[image: Lowercase]

Comment: I think this is one of the best font-id questions yet...  +1..  let this be an example on how to properly ask a font-id question.

Comment: @Matt Thank you! Being a regular at an SE site that has a reputation for being the strictest and most demanding of them all helps you realise how much properly asking a question means. :-)

Comment: That's a very intriguing font. And I agree with Matt - your question is a great example of how to ask for a font ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The name of this font is [Replica](http://lineto.com/The+Fonts/Font+Categories/Text+Fonts/Replica/) and it was designed by the Zurich-based studio [Norm](http://www.norm.to/).

[image]

Comment: Did you just happen to know it, or how did you find it?

Comment: I found it by chance. I read this blog post about the FITC Tokyo Titles: http://fontsinuse.com/uses/9096/fitc-tokyo-2015-titles